# How to inherit from one of two base classes, deciding on runtime

Tags: python, oop

A Base class named MyClass is present in one file and another Base class MyClass1 is present in another file.

I have two platforms suse10 and suse11 linux. I have a script where based on the platform MyClass.py file will be disabled for suse10 and MyClass1 will be disabled for suse11.

Now i want another Class in another file common for both the platforms to inherit any one of these classes based on the platform. How can i do it

Let us consider MyClass.py to be

```py
class MyClass(AbsClass):
    def __init__(self,Sample):
         /*Constructor func*/

    /*Class Func*/
```

And MyClass1.py be

```py
class MyClass1(AbsClass):
    def __init__(self,Sample):
        /*Constructor func*/

    /*Class Func with some additional functionalities*/
```

I want SubClass.py file as

```py
from MyClass import MyClass
from MyClass1 import MyClass1
class SubClass(MyClass or MyClass1 based on which is enabled):
    def __init__(self,Sample):
        MyClass.__init__(self,Sample):
```

In the script

```py
if PLATFORM==suse10
    rm -r MyClass.py /* Deletes and disables it */
elif PLATFORM==suse11
    rm -r MyClass1.py /* Deletes and disables it */
```

Consider this as a abstract code .Also consider there are 100 platforms which enable and disable the python files. How can i dynamically load the class files using the existence of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import conditionally:

```
if is_suse10():
    from MyClass import MyClass as Base
elif is_suse11():
    from MyClass1 import MyClass1 as Base
else:
    raise UnsupportedPlatformError()

class SubClass(Base):
    def __init__(self, Sample):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__(Sample)
```

Note that the way you’re calling parent’s `__init__` is a little unconventional, so I changed that as well.

Comment: Strogonoff, is there any another way of importing conditionally like using inspect of class name bcoz consider there are more than 90 platforms which enable and disable these classes

Comment: ``MyClass = importlib.import_module(platform_name).MyClass`` – https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html

Comment: This will get only MyClass for all the platforms. And some platforms will fail due to the non availibility of MyClass. What about MyClass1?

Comment: Per my ``importlib`` example, if you have available a Python module called ``suse10`` that defines ``MyClass``, and you compute your variable platform_name to equal ``"suse10"``, then MyClass will be the one under ``suse10.MyClass``. If you have available a Python module called ``suse11`` that defines ``MyClass``, and you compute your variable platform_name to equal ``"suse11"``, then MyClass will be the one under ``suse11.MyClass``. In your example, you’d make ``MyClass`` available as ``suse10.MyClass``, and ``MyClass1`` as ``suse11.MyClass``. One of them ends up as your base `MyClass`.

Comment: But as in the shell script , i will delete the module for that particular platform. How to check for the availability of that particular module and import it from the module.

Comment: If for some reason your platform_name will be set to "suse11" but your suse11 module is unavailable (?), you can catch the ``ImportError``.

Comment: The stuff was working when i caught import error for the existence of the class , Thank you @Anton Strogonoff

Answer (score 2):

You could define the base class depending on the platform

```
if platform == 'Suse10':
    class BaseClass:
        ...

elif platform == 'Suse11':
    class BaseClass:
        ...
else:
    raise Exception('Unexpected platform')


class MyClass(BaseClass):
   ....
```

or something more elegant like this

```
class BaseClassSuse10:
   ...

class BaseClassSuse11:
   ...

if platform == 'Suse10':
    BaseClass = BaseClassSuse10
elif platform == 'Suse11':
    BaseClass = BaseClassSuse11
...

MyClass(BaseClass):
    ...
```

or, if you have a module `base.py` where you define all base classes

```
if platform == 'Suse10':
    from base import BaseClass10 as BaseClass
elif platform == 'Suse11':
    from base import BaseClass11 as BaseClass
```

Comment: The second or third option is what I would recommend (defining both classes and then assign a specific one a new name which you use in the subclass / importing using an alias). Probably the conditional import is the most pythonic way to go.